# Custom theme - pages in menu

Tags: themes, menus, pages, links

I am glad for the opportunity to be a member of this community. Lately I decide to start learning wordpress and theme building so this is my first post here. I read some tutorials around the net about how to construct a custom theme. My question is, how can I build my custom menu? For example I have the template on psd, I slice it and then I want to integrate it on wordpress. I support that first I build pages. Then how can I build a menu with custom css/xhtml which every link point to the pages I created? Maybe the description it's not clear but I suppose you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.0 WordPress includes new menu system. It allows to setup menu items in administration area easily and associate menus with specific places in theme templates.

It outputs decent list-based markup (pre-filled with classes) that you can style with CSS (and customize if needed).

See [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) for where to start.